# Query kubectl resources in config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a `yaml` file that looks like this

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello-cron-job
  namespace: hello-world
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
            - name: services
              value: $(kubectl get service -A)
            command: ["echo", "$services"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: scripts
              mountPath: /tmp/python
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: scripts
            configMap:
              name: test-scripts`
```

I'd like to get all currently running services and set `services` env variable to those running services. Is it possible to achieve this?

I've tried using

```
- name: services
  value: $(kubectl get service -A)
```

but it just treats `value` as string.

Comment: You probably need to set up a [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/service-accounts/) and then have your script use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/) to retrieve the list of Services when it runs (there is an [official Python SDK](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/)).  Kubernetes doesn't support command substitution in `env:` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

- you want to list services dynamically (at every cron execution)
- you want to pass the list of services statically (list of services when applying the manifest)

#### Listing services dynamically

If you want to list the services at every cron execution, you'll need to run the `kubectl` command **from inside** the pod. You'll also need to create a dedicated `ServiceAccount` for your `CronJob`. This `ServiceAccount` must have the right permissions to list all services in the cluster. For that, you can define a `ClusterRole` (to list all services in the cluster) and link it to your `ServiceAccount` using a `ClusterRoleBinding`. This is similar to what [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) explained in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979310/query-kubectl-resources-in-config-file/76979786?noredirect=1#comment135710101_76979310).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: hello-cron-job
  namespace: hello-world
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: list-all-services
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: hello-cron-job
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: list-all-services
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: hello-cron-job
  namespace: hello-world
```

From there, you can define your `CronJob` using that service account:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello-cron-job
  namespace: hello-world
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: alpine/k8s:1.28.0
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              services=$(kubectl get services -A -o name)
              echo $services
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          serviceAccountName: hello-cron-job
```

Notice how `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName` is set to the previously created `ServiceAccount`.

I'm using [`alpine/k8s` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/k8s) here, as it has already `kubectl` installed.

#### Listing services statically

In case you only want to pass the list of services when applying the manifest, you can define your `CronJob` in a file (let's say `cronjob.yaml`):

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello-cron-job
  namespace: hello-world
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            env:
            - name: services
              value: "$SERVICES"
            command: ["echo", "$(services)"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Then, substitute `$SERVICES` value (with `envsubst`) before `kubectl apply`ing:

```bash
SERVICES=$(kubectl get svc -A -o name) \
    envsubst '$SERVICES' < cronjob.yaml | \
    kubectl apply -f -
```

This will create the `CronJob` object with the right `services` env var (names of the services when applying the manifest).

I've used `-o name` to get only the names of the services, but you can do whatever you want here.

Also note that the command must be `["echo", "$(services)"]` and not `["echo", "$services"]` (see ["Use environment variables to define arguments" in Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments)).

Comment: this seems like it doesn't dynamically get all services for every cronjob. It only gets the services once and then the cronjob will run on those services. I'd like to get the services every time the cronjob runs.

Comment: Of course, because the value of `services` env var is static and contains the value when applying the manifest. In the case you want a dynamic list, then you won't be able to achieve that with env vars. You should run your `kubectl` command from inside your container. Wait a few minutes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Your dynamic solution is exactly what I ended up doing! I'm using Role instead of ClusterRole tho, and also I don't have kubectl in my crontab image, but I figured you can call kubernetes API server by using KUBENETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBENETES_SERVICE_PORT env variables, with the token stored in /var/secrets...